# didReceiveMessage not called after unlocking the iPhone screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

I'm working on Openfire, i implemented it, but there's some problem init.

When i lock iphone and get into app, after that if i send message it never called delegate method `didReceiveMessage`. And stange point is that, user recive messaage that are in group.

Why delegate not called ?

I use this code to set delegate after unlock phone:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(RestartConnection:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];


-(void)RestartConnection:(NSNotification *)messageContent {


    NSMutableDictionary* userInfo = messageContent.object;
    NSLog(@"RestartConnection :- %@",userInfo);

    del = [self appDelegate];
    del._messageDelegate = self;
}
```

i also set my connect method in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self connect];
}
```

and it authorised successfully.

What is problem there ?

**EDIT**

OK DONE
i just add method for join Room in RestartConnection

```
-(void)RestartConnection:(NSNotification *)messageContent {

    NSMutableDictionary* userInfo = messageContent.object;
    NSLog(@"RestartConnection :- %@",userInfo);

    del = [self appDelegate];
    del._messageDelegate = self;

    [self getJoinRoom];
}
```

But it tends to error while sending message to room :

```
RECV: <message xmlns="jabber:client" to="ilesh@peacock/1anqvk75x3" type="error" from="ios@conference.peacock">
<body> The only one </body>
<error code="406" type="modify">
<not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
</error>
</message>
```

so can anyone help ??

Comment: can you confirm if your RestartConnection method is getting called in response to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification event?

Comment: Yes, ofcource it been called after unlock.

Comment: Can you confirm if del is properly initialise and its messageDelegate is property set?

Comment: please see my answer i added.

Comment: The issue appeared to be with your openfire configuration, you need to check if you've specified correctly.